# Can we describe absolutely open separable metrizable spaces "internally"?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let's say that a separable metrizable space $X$ is *absolutely open* if $X$ is open as a subspace of any separable metrizable space it's embedded in.

**Motivation**: We can similarly define absolutely $G_\delta$ spaces, which are precisely complete metric spaces. This is what is meant by "internal" characterization of absolutely $G_\delta$ spaces. Absolutely closed spaces are just compact metric spaces, absolutely $F_\sigma$ spaces are $\sigma$-compact metric spaces. And so on.

**Question**: What is the "internal" characterization of absolutely open spaces? Clearly, it must be a complete metric space. Does a space like that exist?

Comment: There **are** no absolutely open spaces in this sense, absolutely closed is compact is the lowest Borel class we can realise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such space exists. If $X$ separable and metrizable then so is $X\times\mathbb{R}$ but $x\mapsto (x,0)$ does not embed $X$ into $X\times\mathbb{R}$ as an open subset.

Comment: Yes, any such space would have to be empty. Good point!